# How to run 2 simultaneous scoring functions on the same form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to avoid the same repetitive questions for different tests.  How can I score the same questions differently?

```js
var nQ = 8;
var nC = 2;
var a = new Array(8);

a[0] = "Yes";
a[1] = ">84";
a[2] = "Yes";
a[3] = "Yes";
a[4] = "Yes";
a[5] = "Yes";
a[6] = "Yes";
a[7] = "Yes";


function getScore(form) {
  var score = 0;
  var cE;
  var cS;
  for (i = 0; i < nQ; i++) {
    cE = i * nC;
    for (j = 0; j < nC; j++) {
      cS = form.elements[cE + j];
      if (cS.checked) {
        if (cS.value == a[i]) {
          score++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  score = Math.round(score / nQ * 200);
  form.percentage.value = score;
  var correctA = "";
  for (i = 1; i <= nQ; i++) {
    correctA += i + ". " + a[i - 1] + "\r\n";
  }
}

var nQ = 4;
var nC = 2;
var a = new Array(4);

a[0] = "Yes";
a[1] = "<84";
a[3] = "Yes";
a[7] = "No";


function getScore(form) {
  var score = 0;
  var cE;
  var cS;
  for (i = 0; i < nQ; i++) {
    cE = i * nC;
    for (j = 0; j < nC; j++) {
      cS = form.elements[cE + j];
      if (cS.checked) {
        if (cS.value == a[i]) {
          score++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  score = Math.round(score / nQ * 100);
  form.percentage.value = score;
  var correctA = "";
  for (i = 1; i <= nQ; i++) {
    correctA += i + ". " + a[i - 1] + "\r\n";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Test for Stroke</h1>
<form name="Test for diabetes">
  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of Stroke</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <input type="radio" id="a1" name="history of stroke" value="Yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="a2" name="history of stroke" value="No">No<br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    Age</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <input type="radio" id="b1" name="age" value="<84">less than 84<br>
    <input type="radio" id="b2" name="age" value=">84">>84<br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    Female</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <input type="radio" id="c1" name="female" value="Yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="c2" name="female" value="No">No<br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of diabetes mellitus</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <input type="radio" id="d1" name="history of diabetes mellitus" value="Yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="d2" name="history of diabetes mellitus" value="No">No<br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of congestive heart failure</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <input type="radio" id="e1" name="history of congestive heart failure" value="Yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="e2" name="history of congestive heart failure" value="No">No<br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of hypertension</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <input type="radio" id="f1" name="history of hypertension" value="Yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="f2" name="history of hypertension" value="No">No<br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    Proteinuria</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <input type="radio" id="g1" name="proteinuria" value="Yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="g2" name="proteinuria" value="No">No<br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    EGFR less than 45 or end-stage renal disease</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <input type="radio" id="h1" name="eGFR < 45 or end-stage renal disease" value="Yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="h2" name="eGFR < 45 or end-stage renal disease" value="No">No<br>
  </ul>
  <input type="button" value="Get your Score" onClick="getScore(this.form)">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear Answers">
  <p> Score for test 1 = <strong><input class="bgclr" type="text" size="3" style="font-size:17pt;" name="percentage"
        disabled></strong><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Get your Score" onClick="getScore(this.form)">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear Answers">
    <p> Score for test 2 = <strong><input class="bgclr" type="text" size="3" style="font-size:17pt;" name="percentage"
          disabled></strong><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Questions need to stand on their own, and be very explicit when describing what you want to happen vs. what is actually happened. Relevant code needs to be included in the question.

Comment: Unrelated, but you m ight find it more convenient to create an array like this: `a = ['Yes', '> 84', 'Yes', etc...]`

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: You cannot have two functions called the same thing (at the same time). It's unclear what you actually want to be doing here, but chances are it involves scoring a form against an array of answers.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the tip, yes thats exactly my goal. A form with different sets of answers depending on what I'm testing for. In the array tip above, if i wanted to skip a question like a = ['Yes', '> 84', ____, 'Yes'], without scoring points for the one i skipped over, how might i do that.

Comment: @Lamtheram No idea; you'd need a mechanism to mark a question as "skippable" or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the jQuery slogan "write less do more" I rewrote your questionnaire. The centre of everything is the answers array `a`. This is an array of arrays, containing the "correct" (i. e. scoring) answers. Whenever a change is made, to any of the checkboxes, all scores are recalculated. The line

```
ca && ++cnt[j] && (q=uls[i].querySelector("input:checked")) && q.value==ca && ++res[j]
```

is crucial here. It is a sequence of logical tests, concatenated by "AND" operators. As soon as the first `false` is encountered the rest of the statement is not processed any further. The arrays `cnt` and `res` collect the number of relevant questions and the number of correct answers for all (in this case: two) tests (stroke and diabetes).

```js
const ca=[
   ["Yes", "Yes"],
   [">84", "<84"],
   ["Yes"],
   ["Yes", "Yes"],
   ["Yes"],
   ["Yes"],
   ["Yes"],
   ["Yes", "No"]
];
let spans=[...document.querySelectorAll('span.res')];
document.querySelector("input[type=reset]").onclick=ev=>spans.forEach(sp=>sp.textContent="");
document.querySelector("form").onchange=ev=>{
  let cnt=[0,0], res=[0,0], uls=document.querySelectorAll('form ul');  
  ca.forEach((c,i)=>{
    c.forEach((ca,j)=>{ var q;
      // evrything happens here:
      // * the count is incremented for each question (cnt[])
      // * if the answer fits, the score is incremented too (res[])
      ca && ++cnt[j] && (q=uls[i].querySelector("input:checked")) && q.value==ca && ++res[j]
    });
  });
  res.forEach((r,i)=>spans[i].textContent=(200*r/cnt[i]).toFixed(2))
}
```

```html
<h1>Test for Stroke and Diabetes</h1>
<form name="combitest">
  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of Stroke</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="hststroke" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="hststroke" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    Age</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="age" value="<84">less than 84</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="age" value=">84">>84</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    Female</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="female" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="female" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of diabetes mellitus</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="hstdiabetesmellitus" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="hstdiabetesmellitus" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of congestive heart failure</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="hstcongestiveheart failure" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="hstcongestiveheart failure" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of hypertension</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="hsthypertension" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="hsthypertension" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    Proteinuria</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="proteinuria" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="proteinuria" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    EGFR less than 45 or end-stage renal disease</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="eGFRlt45orendstagerenal" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="eGFRlt45orendstagerenal" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>
  
  <p> Score for test 1 (Stroke) =   <span class="res"></span><br><br>
  <p> Score for test 2 (Diabetes) = <span class="res"></span><br><br>
  <input type="reset" value="Clear Answers">
    
  </form>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, looks a lot more easier to work with. When trying to incorporate this into a standard html page, I'm having difficulty running the query script. I tried adding a button but to no avail. How might i be able to run the code when someone fills out the questions and will it then update from 1 change like it does here on stack overflow. @cars10m

Comment: I used the "delegated event listener" `document.querySelector("form").onchange=ev=>...` to react on any changes to the checkboxes within the `<form>`. As soon as anything is "changed", the calculation is triggered. You can change this back to anything else (like a button-click), but from a user perspective it is always nice to get a response without having to click a "calculate" button.

Comment: I agree and the button would be more so to start this delegated event listener which doesnt seem to be working for me outside of the snippet above. Is there any way you know of starting it as soon as a page renders.

Comment: Either put it into a `<script>` section *after* your `</body>` tag or put it into the `document.onload`event function, like `document.onload=function(){ document.querySelector("form").onchange=ev=>...  }`.